# Fixed Image On Scroll Shifting Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19451/

I am building a website using Bootstrap 3. On scroll I have an image that sticks to the page by changing position to fixed. This works however it always shifts out of place once it turns fixed. I am aware this has something to do with the margins (and I have played with pixels and this seems to practically solve the problem, the margin-left needs to be a % for the responsive website). Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <h2 class="white">Some Text</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <img class="img-responsive screen-phone" src="img/phone.png">
            </div>
</div><!--END ROW-->
```

CSS

```
.screen-phone{
    max-width:300px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:25%;
    z-index:999;

}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>1120){
        $('.screen-phone').css('position','fixed').css('top','0');
    }else{$('.screen-phone').css('position','static');
    };
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

CSS

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.screen-phone{
    max-width:300px;
    margin-top:25px;
    //margin-left:25%;
    z-index:999;
 float:right;
}
```

JavaScript

```
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */

$(document).ready(function(){

    // var stickyPhone = ($#)

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>500){
            $('.screen-phone').css('position','fixed').css('right','0');
        }else{$('.screen-phone').css('position','relative');
        };
    });
});
```

I Removed the margin-left and added a float right. Then on the JS i changed the position to left:0. It seams to work.

Comment: This just causes the phone to move completely off the screen when put on the site and when done in the Fiddle, it still shifts from it's initial position.

Answer (score 0):

I made several changes that made it work:

1. Move the class name to the `div` element instead of the `img` element
2. Make the CSS changes only when necessary by using a boolean variable
3. The 500 pixel test was too long for the size of the text.  When invoked, the change in size due to the image being fixed would shrink below 500 forcing another change, and so on.

See the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19475/

Comment: This doesn't stop the phone from jumping it's position still. When it hits the point it sticks it still shifts around. This is true in both the fiddle and in the website I'm testing this on.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what behavior you are looking for.  See updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19484/.  I added more text and made the test based on 500 pixels.  Once you scroll down 500 pixels the phone will appear in the fixed position on the screen.

Comment: The image should already be loaded in the DIV like my original fiddle. When it changes to "fixed" it should just stick to the page. It's margins shouldn't shift. Therefore it shouldn't jut out of place upwards, downwards, left or right. This is a similar concept to when you're scrolling down a web page and a side column stays in place with ads. These don't shift around when they stick in place, they just simply stick in place.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured this out. What needs to be done is you put a separate class on the containing DIV. You give it left:(whatever your percent value is here). You take margin-left OFF the containing image. If using Bootstrap like me, you'll have to get around margin issues you can create two classes like I did to remove the margin of the row and col-sm-7. In my case I did:

```
.screen-phone{
 max-width:300px;
 margin-top:25px;
 /*Removed margin-left:25%*/
 z-index:999;

}

.sticker{
 left:25%
}

.zero-row{
 margin:0;
}

.no-margin{
 width:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row zero-row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <h2 class="white">Some Text</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 no-margin sticker">
            <img class="img-responsive screen-phone" src="img/phone.png">
        </div>
</div><!--END ROW-->
```

Updated Fidde: https://jsfiddle.net/1chkghhq/1/